# php function for linux time conversion

Tags: php, linux, function, time

I'm new to PHP and I need a PHP function that converts Linux times like 1396310400 from `$variable` and returns a human-readable date like 1. apr. 2014! (time of day not needed)? Any suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: [`date`](http://php.net/date)

Comment: I would like to point out that isn't LINUX time but UNIX time and I believe that UNIX time is the underlying time for ALL operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

`echo date('d/m/Y', $time_linux);`

read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to learn how to modify the result to show exactly what you want.

Comment: I've tried to implement this in a function, but I'm getting an error!

function overtagelsesdato($time_linux) {
echo date('d/m/Y', $time_linux);  
  }
    return $time_linux;

Comment: Why are you returning $time_linux? `echo` Allready print's it. If you want it to be returnd insert it to a variable and return that variable.

Comment: OK - I've tried this, but it's not working?

function overtagelsesdato($time_linux) {
echo date('d/m/Y', $time_linux);  
  }

Comment: I'm running wpallimport plugin in WP with linux time variable from a xml-file and the function 'overtagelsesdato' is not returning anything after import is run!?

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for your input.

This worked and returned a human readable date into my wpallimport run - at first I just did not understand the syntax:

```
function overtagelsesdato($time_linux) {
```

echo date('d/m/Y', $time_linux);
}

- thank you OfirH!